# UNION ALL IS NOT WORKING WITH GROUP BY IN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a query that shows whether the employees has taken what kind of leave on time card or if they have taken any leave "Vacation".

The output should look like:

```
SELECT   person_number,
         Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN element = 'Overtime' THEN measure
         END) AS overtime_measure_hours,
         Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular Pay' THEN measure
         END) AS regular_measure_hours,
         Sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN elements IN ( 'Double_Time' ) THEN measure
         END) AS Other_amount,
         Max(
         CASE
                  WHEN elements IN ( 'Double_Time' ) THEN 'Double'
         END) AS Other_code
         (
                SELECT papf.person_number,
                       atrb.attribute_category element,
                       atrb.measure            measure_hours,
                       rec.start_date,
                       rec.end_date
                FROM   per_all_people_f papf,
                       hwm_tm_rec rec,
                       fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrbs atrb,
                       fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrb_usages ausage,
                       hwm_tm_statuses status
                WHERE  1=1
                AND    atrb.tm_rep_atrb_id = ausage.tm_rep_atrb_id
                AND    ausage.usages_source_id = rec.tm_rec_id
                AND    ausage.usages_source_version = rec.tm_rec_version
                AND    status.tm_bldg_blk_id = rec.tm_rec_id
                AND    status.tm_bldg_blk_version = rec.tm_rec_version
                AND    rec.tm_rec_type IN ( 'RANGE',
                                           'MEASURE' )
                AND    papf.person_number = '101928'
                AND    trunc (status.date_to) = to_date ('31/12/4712', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                       --and atrb.attribute_category in( 'Overtime','Regular Pay', 'Double_Time')
                AND    trunc (sh21.start_time) BETWEEN trunc(:P_From_Date) AND    trunc(:P_To_Date) )
GROUP BY person_number
UNION ALL
SELECT   person_number,
         sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN element = 'Overtime' THEN measure
         END) AS overtime_measure_hours,
         sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN elements LIKE 'Regular Pay' THEN measure
         END) AS regular_measure_hours,
         sum(
         CASE
                  WHEN absence_name IN ( 'Vacation' ) THEN abs_duration
         END) AS Other_amount,
         max(
         CASE
                  WHEN absence_name IN ( 'Vacation' ) THEN absence_name
         END) AS Other_code
         (
                SELECT papf.person_number,
                       atrb.attribute_category element,
                       atrb.measure            measure_hours,
                       rec.start_date,
                       rec.end_date,
                       abs.NAME     absence_name,
                       abs.duration abs_duration
                FROM   per_all_people_f papf,
                       hwm_tm_rec rec,
                       fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrbs atrb,
                       fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrb_usages ausage,
                       hwm_tm_statuses status,
                       anc_absence_types_vl abs
                WHERE  1=1
                AND    atrb.tm_rep_atrb_id = ausage.tm_rep_atrb_id
                AND    ausage.usages_source_id = rec.tm_rec_id
                AND    ausage.usages_source_version = rec.tm_rec_version
                AND    status.tm_bldg_blk_id = rec.tm_rec_id
                AND    status.tm_bldg_blk_version = rec.tm_rec_version
                AND    rec.tm_rec_type IN ( 'RANGE',
                                           'MEASURE' )
                AND    papf.person_number = '101928'
                AND    trunc (status.date_to) = to_date ('31/12/4712', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                       --and atrb.attribute_category in( 'Overtime','Regular Pay', 'Double_Time')
                AND    trunc (sh21.start_time) BETWEEN trunc(:P_From_Date) AND    trunc(:P_To_Date)
                AND    abs.absence_type_id = atrb.absence_type_id )
GROUP BY person_number
```

Although these queries are working separately it is not working with group by on each subquery.

If I merge the two queries, the issue I am having is with `Other_code` & `other_amount`. These columns have values from two different tables.

How can I solve this?

Output should be returned for the two dates p_from_date- 01-Jan-2021 and p_to_date- 31-Jul-2021 as:

```
 Person_Number          Overtime_measure_hours          Regular_Measure_hours        Other_code        Other_amount   
   101928                   18                          15                            Double_Time         34
   101928                   18                          15                            Vacation            1
```

i.e. `Overtime_measure_hours`, `Regular_Measure_hours` and `Other_amount` should have the sum of these values.

Comment: It's missing 2 `FROM`. And wouldn't it be easier to have 1 query without a union. Just with colums like `(Person_Number , Overtime_measure_hours, Regular_Measure_hours, Double_time_amount, Vacation_amount)`

Comment: I need to have vacation & double amount in 1 single column.